# Reduce default input box size in bulma

Tags: html, css, angular, bulma

How can I shrink the size of input box ? By default, it's covering all available area which is really not looking good. I need to keep it of medium size and in the center.

[image]

**Code :**

```
<div class="field is-horizontal">
        <label>Saving Account:</label>
        <input class ="input is-primary"> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Mixed it with column classes.

```html
<div class="columns">
  <div class="column is-half is-offset-one-quarter">
    <div class="field is-horizontal">
      <label>Saving Account:</label>
      <input class="input is-primary">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Bulma [document](https://bulma.io/documentation/columns/sizes/).

[See it in action](https://jsfiddle.net/p2ref57a/).